# Не отображаются переменные в контрольных значениях Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Не могу понять почему не отображаются значения переменных при отладке
Фото прикреплю ниже.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо выбрать вкладку "Locals" (Локальные), а не "Watch" (Контрольные значения). Нажмите <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

В текущей вкладке отображаются только введённые вручную переменные.